# Getting 1 or 0 value in materialize's switch class using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, materialize

How do I get a value of 0 if it is checked and a value of 1 if not using PHP?
I am using a materialize CSS framework.

Here's the code for it:

```
<div class='switch'>
    <label>
        Deactivate
        <input id='$Customer_ID' name='switch_Activate'
               type='checkbox' onclick='Switch_Activate(this.id)' checked>
        <span class='lever'></span>
        Activate
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick is to put a hidden input with the same name and `value="0"` before the checkbox so if the checkbox isn't checked, the value from the hidden input (which is 0) will be sent. Also, make sure to set the value of the checkbox to 1

Like this:

```
<div class='switch'>
    <label>
        Deactivate
        <input name='switch_Activate' type='hidden' value='0'>
        <input id='$Customer_ID' name='switch_Activate'
               type='checkbox' onclick='Switch_Activate(this.id)' checked value='1'>
        <span class='lever'></span>
        Activate
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) Good idea :)

Comment: onclick is fired on load, i need 0 by default,your answer gives me 1 with checked default..

Comment: @TamaghnaBanerjee That code was specific to the OP's example. Of course you can remove the `onclick` and `checked` if you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name='switch_Activate' type='hidden' value='0'>
<input id='$Customer_ID' name='switch_Activate' type='checkbox' value='1'>
```

this code has done the trick.